# How to undo committed changes to specific files without rebasing?

Tags: git, github, commit, revert, git-revert

I made about 20 or so commits on this branch.  Somewhere amongst those commits, I accidentally committed multiple refactoring changes to files that shouldn't be in my pull request.  I'd prefer not to rebase one by one for every single file that has unwanted changes, that would be a headache and a nightmare, because now there are merge conflicts in those files, and I know I want to undo *all* my changes to the specific files.

I just want to create a commit that reverts all the changes I've made just in the files I didn't mean to make changes to.

Comment: If you downvote, can you share why please?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to completely revert changes on target files, and reset them to their state in the root commit (the one you point to with `HEAD~20`).

A straightforward way to do that is :

```
git checkout <that sha> -- file1 file2 file3 ...
# you can also checkout those files one by one, or if you have a list :
git checkout <that sha> -- $(cat list.txt)

# check the content, then run :
git commit
```

Comment: Hmm.. I will try this next time.

Answer (score -1):

So far, the best solution I have is to create a branch off of my current branch, soft reset all the commits I've made.

```
git checkout -b <newBranch> <currentBranch>
git reset --soft HEAD~20
git reset
```

Stage and commit the unwanted files.

```
git add <unwantedFile1>
git add <unwantedFile2>
```

Then commit those changes, then create a revert commit for those changes.

```
git commit -m "Unwanted refactoring"
git log
```

Then copy the sha for that commit, then create a revert commit:

```
git revert <sha>
```

then copy that commit, then switch back to the first branch and cherry pick the revert commit.

```
git cherry-pick <revertSha>
```

Comment: So it seems you know the names of all the files and the SHA of a commit where they were "correct". So why not just restore them straight from that commit? No need for this gavotte... See the other answer.